# jquery accordion height

Tags: jquery-ui, height, accordion

I have two accordion.

> Accordion 1 : Router Info(contains
>   gridRouter)
>
> Accordion 2 : UNC Info(contains
>   gridUNC)

If the gridRouter contains 2 records and gridUNC contains 30 records, the accordion 1 takes space for 30 records (not for 2 records)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try setting the `autoHeight` property to `false`. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#options.

Comment: **This answer is for an outdated version of jQueryUI, please see the one below.**

Answer (score 51):

As of jQuery UI 1.10 the `'autoHeight'` attribute has been deprecated. To achieve the same effect in the new version use `heightStyle: "content"`

See an example:
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height

Answer (score 32):

you should use

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ 

heightStyle: "content" 

});
```

It will set height according to your content. and will not use blank space as height.